# RS507 Ring scanner or TC55 (Kitkat OS) Scanner is not disabled when Async task in operation

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I am fetching data from server with barcode reading using RS507 ring scanner trigger with Bluetooth pairing with TC55 Kitkat device. I found some problems when I tried to use onKeyDown and onKeyUp callback methods to read barcode. So I used onStatus callback method to read barcode i.e. scanner.read(). I am trying to stop scanner when my Async task operation is in progress, because it causes multiple request calls when I press scanner trigger button multiple times. I tried to use scanner.cancelRead(), but it doesn't helpful. The same case is working fine on TC55 Jellybean device, but only difference in Jellybean case is its not supporting Bluetooth pairing utility with RS507 ring scanner. Can anybody please suggest any solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be receiving barcode data through the DataListener interface (onData), not the status interface (onStatus): http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-3/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/Scanner.DataListener.html.  Also, please make sure your RS507 is in SSI mode (details are in the integration guide), you should not need to use onKeyDown or onKeyUp unless the device is operating in HID mode but EMDK requires SSI mode.

CancelRead() will only be useful if you have previously submitted a read, http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-3/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/Scanner.html#read()